# How to prune containerd images and containers?

Tags: containerd

What is the `docker system prune` for containerd? I wanted to delete unused images and stopped containers to free up storage

Answer (score 1):

Since July 2022, [`nerdctl` v0.22.1](https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl/releases/tag/v0.22.1) do includes:

> ### `nerdctl system prune`:
>
> Add `nerdctl system prune` command. Needs `--all`. ([PR 1264](https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl/pull/1264), thanks to @junnplus)

And `nerdctl image prune` ([PR 1194](https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl/pull/1194)) or `nerdctl container prune` ([PR 1180](https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl/pull/1180)) was added in [v0.22.0](https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl/releases/tag/v0.22.0).

> ### `nerdctl system prune`
>
> Remove unused data
>
> ⚠️ Currently, `nerdctl system prune` requires `--all` to be specified.
>
> Usage: `nerdctl system prune [OPTIONS]`
>
> Flags:
>
> - `-a`, `--all`: Remove all unused images, not just dangling ones
> - `-f`, `--force`: Do not prompt for confirmation
> - `--volumes`: Prune volumes
>   Unimplemented docker system prune flags: `--filter`

Answer (score 0):

For now, there's no command to do the same. There is an [issue](https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl/issues/648)
open for `nerdctl` and it seems that some alternative commands are being implemented.

Answer (score 0):

`crictl` provides a CLI for CRI-compatible container runtimes.

With `crictl` we have an option to Remove all unused images similarly to how we used to prune the images using docker cli for docker

Command:

`crictl rmi --prune`